# gtsummary - A customized {n_no5} function to replace cell sizes <5 with "<5"

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to be able to generate tbl_summary tables automatically suppressing display of cell sizes when they are <5. Ie. any value of n from 0-4 in any stat output would be replaced with "<5".

I imagine that this should be possible with a custom function (ie. a version of the {n} function) but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Perhaps this is a feature request as well?

Thanks to the creators for this great package!

```
# Create a custom summary function
n_no5 <- function (x) {
  # myct<-  get the count of x in current by group for variable .. 
  # tried this: Does not work. 
  myct<- sum (!is.na(x))

  # return the following
  ifelse(myct<5, "<5", myct)
}

mydata %>% select (bygroup, variable) %>% 
tbl_summary 
  ( by="bygroup", 
    statistic=list (all_categorical ~ "{n_no5}")
  )
```

Comment: please provide your mydata  so we can run your code

Comment: There is a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71954590 . First define the function `style_number5()` in the linked issue, the call the function with `tbl_summary ( by="bygroup",  statistic= all_categorical ~ "{n}", digit = all_categorical() ~ style_number5)`

Comment: Thank you so much.  Yes. I knew there would be an easy way.  Brilliant.

Comment: Actually one more question - is there a way to make this apply to the missing data row also?