# Replacing certain values in gt_summary table with a character

Tags: gtsummary

I am making a table using gt_summary package. I have made a cross tabulation of the countries versus number of cases. However, for all the rows with values <5, I want it to be changed to "<5" and put in the footnote

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258280/gtsummary-a-customized-n-no5-function-to-replace-cell-sizes-5-with-5