# gt_summary formatting 0s and grouping like variables

Tags: r, filter, gtsummary, gt

I am trying to use gtsummary to summarize my data and I want to use a subset of my data. Additionally, I want to change the numbers under 10 to be '<10'. I am fidgeting with filter and different aspects of gtsummary that I have found so far, but no luck. gsub is replacing ALL instances of '0' and such, not just the standalone '0' (100 becomes 1-- if I gsub 0 to '-'). Thanks so much for any tips!

I am looking to get certain filters to not show up -- specifically subset of a variable. For housing I want to only show 12k-25k and 25k-100k and not above 100k. I am still getting all of these when I use filter, they just are all populated with 0's instead of their data. I would like to get rid of these rows. Additionally, anything with a '0' I would like to replace with '-' and anything under 10 observations, I would like to change to '<10'. Additionally, I would like to get rid of the automatic precents that get populated in gsummary. Again, thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of your data using the output of `dput()` and your code in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258280 perhaps this. and, yes, please update post with reproducible example